# How are features in programming languages implemented, especially in lower level languages such as C or C++?

Tags: c++

I was looking at a list of new features in the different C++ versions, and I was wondering, how are features implemented in a language? For example, if C++ was to add new features into the language, would they code the features in by using the C++ language itself? Or is another technique to modifying the language?

Comment: you can open the source code for a compiler and standard libraries and see :)  here is the source code for gcc: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc

Comment: Once you get past the beginner stage of learning programming and C++, I recommend you take some time to study programming languages and compilers/interpreters. It's very enlightening and also give you good insights into how programming languages work and how "features" are added to a language. It's also a very good way to learn some new but useful algorithms, data-structures and tools than are generally useful, even outside the field of making programming languages.

Comment: [Bootstrapping (compilers)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers))  The last time someone did this for a mainstream architecture was probably late 1960 early 1970.  These days for a new architecture you would modify the code generation stage to cross-compie for the new target,

Comment: A fair proportion of the evolution between recent C++ standards has been specified and implemented in the standard library, not in the language.   The bulk of the C++ standard library can be implemented in standard C++, but there some aspects that require support of "compiler magic".   For performance reasons, some parts of the standard library targeting some machines might be implemented in other languages (e.g. assembler targeting the particular system) even if it *can* be implemented in C++.

Comment: Richard Critten, is there a name for this process so I can look it up more in depth?

Comment: Boostraping - getting the 1st compiler to work.  cross-compile - compiling on one machine generating code for another architecture. Programming / Computer Science 101 - a compiler is just a program or set of programs (tool-chain: compiler, linker make-like tools etc) you write a compile like any other program.

Answer (score 4):

As you weren't specific about particular features, I'll give you answer only for the last part of your question

> would they code the features in by using the C++ language itself

Yes, they are. This process is called [compiler bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)). The simplest explanation of the process:

1. Write the first version of a compiler on any programming language (e.g. assembler), which allow you implement basic constructions on your new language (C++ in your case)
2. Rewrite this logic on your new language :)
3. Continue add new features until you're satisfied

Comment: So if the body that governs the C++ standard were to decide to add new features, they would use the compiler bootstrapping technique? Or is it as Richard Critten says in his comment?

Comment: It depends on the feature of the standard. If we speak about some new language syntax - yes, bootstrapping will be used. Compiler developers will add new rules to language parser, then they compile this new parser with old compiler. If we speak about features like `std::filesystem` library, then no. It is standard library code and has no connection with compiler bootstrapping.

Answer (score 1):

I diagree with the "bootstrapping" answer - as Richrad Critten notes in the comments, that hasn't been done in decades. It's entirely obsolete.

Languages like C and C++ are *compiled*. That is to say, there is a program called a compiler, which reads source code (text) and emits binary code that can be directly executed on the CPU.

The basics of this are not very hard - languages such as C++ are built around function calls, and every CPU from the last few decades has direct support for that.

Sure, new standards add new functions to the Standard Library, but that just means that the compiler comes with a set of pre-written functions. For quite a few of those functions, earlier versions were shipped as part of the Boost libraries, instead of the Standard Library, which shows there is nothing special.

But the core part of the language also includes some bits that are not simply function calls. In this case, the compiler authors need to devise a mapping of C++ source code text to CPU assembly code. That mapping is quite complex, especially for optimizing compilers. But this mapping can still be expressed in any language - there is no problem with a C compiler written in C++, or a C++ compiler written in C. And for the same reason, a compiler for C++20 can easily be written in C++11. Sure, that C++20 compiler cannot use `std::string_view` itself, useful as it might be, but it can still use a `MyOwn::string_view` class instead.

Comment: I agree that there is absolutely no need to write compiler on the same language that it compile. You, basically, can write C++ compiler on bash and everything will work. Even so, the question was about C++, for which every popular compiler is written on C++ itself. Moreover `llvm` is compiled with `C++14` standard, but it does not mean that my answer is incorrect. You still can compile `clang` with older version, than you can compile the same code again with freshly created version of `clang` and interrupt "decades of non-bootstrapping age".